# completion:@escaping (Bool) -> ()と他の引数を組み合わせる場合

Tags: swift, swift5

Swift5で、ある特定の処理の終了後に次の処理を行いたいです。
以下の例だと、myFunction内部のprint("A")を実行したあとに、print("success")を実行しています。

```
import Foundation

@objc func myFunction(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> () ) {
        print("A")
        completion(true)
}

func testA_Func()
{
    myFunction { (status) in
        if status {
            print("success")
        }
    }
}

testA_Func()
```

以下のように、myFunctionに引数を追加したところtestFuncAから呼び出す方法がわかりません。

```
import Foundation

@objc func myFunction(argA:String,argB:String,completion:@escaping (Bool) -> () ) {
        print("A")
        print("argA = " + argA)
        print("argB = " + argB)
        completion(true)
}

func testA_Func()
{
    let argAstring = "testA"
    let argBstring = "testB"
    myFunction { (argAstring,argBstring,status) in
        if status {
            print("success")
        }
    }
}

testA_Func()
```

どのように、testA_Func()内部からmyFunctionに引数を渡してあげれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文を拝見した範囲で推察したところ、どうも質問者さんは、Swiftの**Trailing Closure**をご存じないのではないかと見受けられます。

[The Swift Programming Language - Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

ネット検索すれば、日本語のTrailing Closuresに関する情報が複数見つかりますので、それらで学習するといいでしょう。

Trailing Closureは、SwiftのSugar Syntax（糖衣構文）のひとつで、文法通りに記述すると、文字数が多くなったり、プログラマ（人間）が読解しにくくなるコードを、簡潔にかつ理解しやすいように置き換えた構文です。
Trailing Closureを使わずに、関数`myFunction`（後者の、引数が3つある方）を呼び出すコードを書くと、こうなります。

```
myFunction(argA: argAstring, argB: argBstring, completion: { (status) in
    if status {
        print("success")
    }
})
```

関数の引数をリストするかっこ（()）のうちの閉じかっこ（)）が、遠く離れたところに位置するので、みおとしがちになりますね。引数の中の、後置するクロージャは、かっこの後ろに書くようにしましょう、そうすれば閉じかっこを忘れずにすむというのが、Tailing Closureです。
ここまで学習すれば、正しい関数の呼び出し方は、別回答者さんの示したコードになることが、理解していただけると思います。

Answer (score 1):

今手元に開発環境がないので動作チェックしていませんが、下記のとおりでどうでしょうか。

```
myFunction(argA: argAstring, argB: argBstring) { (status) in
    if status {
        print("success")
    }
}
```